# How to use phonegap-facebook-plugin under CLI 5.2 / PGB

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

This question is related to the issue I opened few days ago https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1173

- Android Log: http://pastebin.com/iiTGP20G
- IOS Log: http://pastebin.com/UShGmpNy

**Summary**: be able to use phonegap-facebook-plugin under CLI-5.2

As I have an important release to do and the repo owner is not responding, I'm trying to find a solution to build my application on PGB with official phonegap-facebook-plugin.

I'm looking for one of these:

- Some tips or ideas to fix the error given to fork and fix
- A way to see recent repo's forks (too many fork to be shown: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/network) maybe someone fix it...
- A fork URL with a fix :)
- Any useful suggestion...

Comment: from your Android log: `4: /project/phonegap-facebook-plugin/nego-FacebookLib/ant-build does not exist.`

Comment: Yes, I read the log :) 
I think "ant-build" should be a folder because it's define on this file: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/FacebookLib/custom_rules.xml
I will try to create it manually...

Comment: If you need `ant`, it is still supported, `gradle` is now the default. The following blog post will help: [Android Builds Now Using Gradle By Default](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle/). Go to the bottom of the post to force `ant`.

Comment: @Weby, Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Sorry for this late answer... not enough time to fork and fix the plugin for the moment... maybe tomorrow :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

You have to add (edit) you config.xml as it:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-facebook-plugin"  source="npm">
   <param name="APP_ID" value="XXXX" />
   <param name="APP_NAME" value="XXXXX" />
</gap:plugin>
```

**Bonus:**
If you want to update to a new Facebook SDK juste change **phonegap-facebook-plugin** by **cordova-plugin-facebook4** which refer to this fork https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4