# PhoneGap Cloud Build: Correct facebookConnectPlugin installation

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, phonegap-build

I'm sure this is going to be so trivial, but have had a number of tries and being the last thing I need to configure before I can deploy the private test is driving me mad.

This question extends off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215255/phonegap-build-facebookconnectplugin-not-defined/33726427#33726427), my **config.xml** is established in the same way, this part is a no brainer.  I have also got in my `<head>`:

`<script type='text/javascript' src="./js/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>`

I have tried both **./facebookConnectPlugin.js** as well as **./js/facebookConnectPlugin.js**, so part (a) of my question is, how can I determine what is the correct relative path without seeing the directory? I can't find its install location to verify.

Next part of the question follows the advice I received from somewhere, that instead of using the usual [device ready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html) event, to use the **window.onload**:

```
window.onload = onDeviceReady;
...
function onDeviceReady() {
    onDeviceReadyFacebook();
    ...
}
...
function onDeviceReadyFacebook() {
    // ?
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    if (!window.cordova) {
        // Initialize - only executed when testing in the browser.
        facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(<APP_ID>);
    }
}
```

I have tried the **window.fbAsyncInit** both inside and out of the call I make for **onDeviceReadyFacebook**, trying to follow the advice from different forums...

So finally the error occurs within the call I have made to login:

```
function fb_login(){
    var login_data = {};

    client.cmd          = "login";
    login_data.userid   = user_id;
    login_data.cmd      = "login";

    facebookConnectPlugin.login([
        'user_about_me',
        'email',
        'user_status',
        'user_posts',
        'user_photos',
        'user_videos',
        'user_friends'
    ],function(response) {
        // success
        ...
```

Saying that the facebookConnectPlugin is undefined.  After sligthly modifying different areas and everything else about the app is working, I would generally say that I'm not specifying the right source url for the primary JS file...

One last question on this topic: if I have correctly put in my [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy), is there any reason I need to use a plugin when I can just use the Facebook **all.js** they provide as is used in the browser version?  I have got my key hash and other properties defined to add the android platform, I would have thought I can specify those attributes to match the platform...

**EDIT**: The plugin branch in question is located [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/a5c6be9/README.md).

**UPDATE 2:**
@JesseMonroy650:
Yes; a few things are definitely becoming clearer, but I did switch to **cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando**, but adding that made the build crash, the log file result saying the message "...-FacebookLib/ant-build does not exist".  I found the exact problem happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526773/how-to-use-phonegap-facebook-plugin-under-cli-5-2-pgb), so I've now tried the same npm plugin and preference settings that was used there.  It now builds, but I have the same problem (facebookConnectPlugin is undefined).

*However*, I checked the [repo](https://github.com/dhatawesomedude/phonegap-facebook-plugin) again this morning, specifically the path:

`/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html`

To see what I am *crucially* missing :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebookConnectPlugin.js">/script>
```

So hopefully if I copy off this example, I should be alright now.  Will be trying again tonight.

Any help is always very appreciated!

Comment: Okay. You are way out in left field. I'm sure where you got any of that; perhaps an outdated example. I'm going to answer on your other post. You may want to kill this. Then again, you have so many misconceptions I might want to make comments here.

Comment: Are you making any headway?

Answer (score 0):

The code added to `index.html` has finally resolved the issue.  I tidied up the actual call to the login as demonstrated, but ultimately the variable wasn't found because I hadn't done the script include.  Confusion over the scripts to include and what path they would be.

**BIG** relief!!! Props to you @JesseMonroy650 for steering me in the right direction of a deprecated plugin.